# Randomly Set Width of Image with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, random, width

Am looking to set the width of an image to a random number between 25% and 75%, Is this possible with Jquery? So far I have tried everything I can think of and research but to no avail..

Anyone out there that can help?

Im not great with JQuery so help would be Greatly Appreciated

I am trying to use the plugin Instafeed to randomise image sizes from a Users account tagged with a specific hashtag so entirely I have:

I need the .insta-box to randomly generate a size each time it loads an image...

```
<style>
.insta-box {float:center;clear:both;margin:0px;padding:0%;max-height:50%;overflow:hidden;border-width:0;display:inline-block;}</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function ($) {
        var userId = "UID";
        var accessToken = "Token";
        var numDisplay = "9";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+userId+"/media/recent/?    access_token="+accessToken,
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < numDisplay; i++) {                      
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+10+"%";
            $(".insta-box").css('width', rand);
$(".insta").append("<div class='insta-box'><a target='_blank' href='"+data.data[i].link+"'>
    <img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url+"'width='auto'/><a></div>"); 
            $(".insta").css('width', '100%');
            }    

            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Short answer; Yes you can. Show us some code... What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: @PeterVR Updated initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go, a width between 25% and 75% of the window width: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xn2r59x3/1/)**

```
var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*75)+25;
var width=Math.round(($(window).width()/100)*rand);
$('img').width(width);
```

**UPDATE:**

just replace this line `$(".insta-box").css('width', rand);` with the following

```
 $(".insta-box").eq(i).css('width', rand);
```

Comment: I can see it works on your fiddle when I changed the image to have the same id as my images will have when put in by the instafeed plugin but when loaded up the images randomise the sizes, example here www.bchsalevelmaths.co.uk/test The gallery at the bottom is what I am trying to affect with this randomise

Comment: @TaylorMudd In your example, every image has an id of "instafeedimage." If you want to target more than one element, use classes, not ids.

Comment: @scdavis41 ah yeah.. stupid mistake on my behalf but that didnt change anything..

Comment: @AminJafari It is more than likely my implementation but could you possibly have a look at my initial post code and direct me where to paste what? Sorry, I've been thrown in at the deep end with this project..

Comment: I think there might be a problem with the css for img `hight:auto;` remove that and let me know if that fixes it

Comment: also try writing this script after the initialization of foundation script

Comment: Changed both of those and still nothing... This is so frustrating because I feel so close yet so far at the same time haha 

Would you like to move this to chat for ease of comms?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm swamped write now, I come and go, therefore can't chat, can you tell me how those imgs are appended, using the plugin? if so, then try writing the code after the plugin takes effect, maybe use a `setTimeout() ` or something. if that wont work, then the plugin is definitely conflicting and wont let it be and there's nothing you can do then as far as I know!

Comment: The plugin takes the images from instagram and puts them into the page as the template script dictates

Comment: @AminJafari I changed around what I am using and got it to work initially now I face one final (hopefully) issue... Please check new code in my question to see if there is anything wrong that would cause the images to not randomise size, it generates a width fine but sets that one width to all ".insta-box" classes instead of changing it each time..

Answer (score 0):

This will set the width of the image to a random percentage between 25-75:

```
width = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 25).toString();
$("#instafeedimage").width(width + '%');
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fumuLbb5/).

Comment: This has the same issue as Amin Jafari's answer above, I can see it works on your fiddle but it just doesnt want to work in my document, not sure if this is due to the instafeed plugin...